# how do I emerge gcc 9 on gentoo without creating too many processes?

Tags: compiling, gcc, gentoo, optimization

I am stuck on building gcc 9 with lto USE flag, because it is creating over 30 lto processes when I try to do so. At this point, I have to reboot my PC. I think it may have to do with the [new lto features](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html) (go for Link-time optimization improvements). I have already tried to manage it by providing COMMON_FLAGS with:

```
--param lto-max-streaming-parallelism=3
```

but looking on the build log, when it starts building it changes the arguments:

```
strip-flags: CFLAGS: changed '-O3 -pipe -march=native --param lto-max-streaming-parallelism=3' to '-pipe -march=native -O2'
```

gcc configuration:

```
Configuring GCC with:
 --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 --prefix=/usr
 --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/9.2.0
 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include
 --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0
 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/man
 --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/info
 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include/g++-v9
 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/python
 --enable-languages=c,c++,d,go,fortran
 --enable-obsolete
 --enable-secureplt
 --disable-werror
 --with-system-zlib
 --enable-nls
 --without-included-gettext
 --enable-checking=yes
 --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/
 --with-pkgversion=Gentoo 9.2.0-r2 p3
 --disable-esp
 --enable-libstdcxx-time
 --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto
 --enable-shared
 --enable-threads=posix
 --enable-__cxa_atexit
 --enable-clocale=gnu
 --enable-multilib
 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64
 --disable-altivec
 --disable-fixed-point
 --enable-targets=all
 --enable-libgomp
 --disable-libmudflap
 --disable-libssp
 --enable-systemtap
 --enable-vtable-verify
 --enable-lto
 --with-isl
 --disable-isl-version-check
 --enable-default-pie
 --enable-default-ssp
```

Comment: What is your `MAKEOPTS` environment variable set to? Normally you can find this setting in `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

Comment: You may have to open a bug at bugs.gentoo.org asking to allow the `--param lto-max-streaming-parallelism=3` `LDFLAGS` through. It looks like this would be an appropriate flag to place in `LDFLAGS`—did you try adding it there rather than in `CFLAGS`?

Comment: I did not, I am trying it now